# Getting User Info from Auth0 for multiple React Apps

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I've got two react apps, One main called the Home app and one called the dashboard.
I'm managing my auth with auth0, I'm login in/signing up with the Home app, but I also want to get the user details in the dashboard app.

I tried to install and use `@auth0/auth0-react` in the dashboard app as well, the Logout function Is working but I've got the user object as undefined.

Please help!

Comment: Can you share what have you tried so far to get user object. Then I can assist